# Run Code based on User Input (Python3,Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a code that requires a user input in the beginning:

```
var = input("Do you want A (Type: A) or an B (Type: B)?")
```

Based on this input, it will run a specific set of code.  I know how to achieve this using something like:

```
if var = 'A':
    run code...

elif: var = 'B':
    run other code...

else:
    print ('Incorrect Input')
```

My problem is I'm actually merging two different and very long sets of codes together into one.   The problem with the method above is due to the whitespace constrains of a Python "if" statement -- I don't want to have to indent a thousand lines of code by hand.  Is there a better way to achieve this same concept of running code based on a user input that won't require me to indent everything?

Comment: Not sure why all the negative downvotes...

Comment: I suspect it's non-obvious what you've tried, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I like the answer provided (which is what I meant when I commented "call a function").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a function depending on the input.

```
def func_a():
    #Do stuff here...
    return

def func_b():
    #Do stuff here...
    return

type = input("A/B: ").lower()

if type == "a":
    func_a()
elif type == "b":
    func_b()
else:
    print("Invalid option.")
```

Another way could be to call a script using `os.system()`.

```
if type == "a":
    os.system("python script_a.py")
elif type == "b":
    os.system("python script_b.py")
else:
    print("Invalid option.")
```

And, if I'm understanding your question right, here's a way of running a function based on user input using a dictionary. This way you don't need to type out a hundred if-else statements.

```
types = {"A": func_a,
         "B": func_b}

choice = input("A/B: ")

types[choice]()
```